# How i can get all events from all registered users by using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I work on iPhone application that grab events from different channel and show them on map.
Now i try to grab Facebook events in my DB. 
I make this request

```
SELECT name, venue, location, start_time, update_time FROM event WHERE update_time>1358294400
```

But it doesn't work. Facebook return

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1358528400. The current unix time is 1358761880.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 190, 
    "error_subcode": 463
  }
}
```

How can i get events by `update_time` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can not. Since-

> The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with ***** in the tables.

and `updated_time` is not an indexable column. Only `eid` and `name` are indexable in the table `event`.

So, simply get all the data and then filter manually according to the `updated_time`

Comment: How can i simply get all the data?

Comment: Depends on what's your requirement. You may use this- `SELECT name, venue, location, start_time, update_time FROM event WHERE eid in (select eid from event_member where uid = $id)`

Comment: But i need all event from all user.

Comment: I thought you will give it a try by yourself :P. Well, you may try something like this: `SELECT eid,name,pic,start_time,end_time,location,venue.id,privacy,all_members_count,creator,description,attending_count,can_invite_friends FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =me()) AND start_time >= now() ) and privacy='OPEN' and venue.id<>'' AND start_time >=now() ORDER BY start_time ASC limit 5000`

Comment: You should start figuring out the problem after the hints. :) 
Well, this query is working perfectly fine for me. Check if you have the `friends_event` permission or not. And if I had helped you out , you can mark this as answer.

Comment: it's working but only for my friends..  But i need events from all facebook users.. Can i do this?

Comment: ok.. If i'll not find anything i'll mark this as answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi i have question about this request.. I can't get venue.street

Comment: Are you sure the `street` is defined in the `event`? If yes, report the bug.

Comment: it defined in venue struct.

Comment: Report the bug to facebook.